# How to keep rotating a FontAwesome-icon in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I'd like to keep rotating a icon from FontAwesome in Processing java. (the fa-spin icon to be precisely.) (\f110)

Link to effect: [Example](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated)

#### My create-function for an icon

```
public void drawIcon(int size, String icon, float custom_height) {

    font = createFont("fontawesome-webfont.ttf",size);
    textFont(font);
    if(icon != null && !icon.trim().isEmpty()) {
        text(icon, width / 2, height / custom_height);
    }

}
```

#### Initialization object + called method

To create my icon, I initialized an object and called my function in the draw()-method  :

```
Content content = new Content(); // content object
PFont font;  // font object

public void draw() {
     content.drawIcon(46, "\uf110", 7);
}
```

I found the rotate/translate methods from the documentation, but can't figure out the correct parameters for rotating this icon 360 degrees continiously.

#### Attempt

```
public void draw() {
     rotate(degrees(360));
     content.drawIcon(46, "\uf110", 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommended loading the font once in `setup()` rather than potentially multiple times a second in `drawIcon()`.

You can simply use `text()` after you've loaded the font and called `textFont()`.

e.g.

```
PFont font;  // font object

public void setup() {
     font = loadFont("fontawesome-webfont.ttf",46);
    textFont(font);
}

public void drawIcon(String icon, float custom_height) {

    if(icon != null && !icon.trim().isEmpty()) {
        text(icon, width / 2, height / custom_height);
    }

}
```

In terms of rotating, at the moment you're specifying the same angle continuously. What you probably want to do is create a variable to keep track of the current angle, increment the angle and pass that to `rotate()` in `draw()`.

```
PFont font;  // font object
int angle = 0;

public void setup() {
     font = loadFont("fontawesome-webfont.ttf",46);
    textFont(font);
}

public void drawIcon(String icon, float custom_height) {

    if(icon != null && !icon.trim().isEmpty()) {
        text(icon, width / 2, height / custom_height);
    }

}

public void draw() {
//increment angle (angle++; would to the same, but hopefully expanded version is easier to read)
     angle = angle + 1;
     rotate(degrees(angle));
     content.drawIcon("\uf110", 7);
}
```

Be sure to checkout the [Rotate Processing example](https://processing.org/examples/rotate.html) as well.

You may notice that the symbol might not rotate from the centre.
This will require you to use multiple coordinate spaces using `pushMatrix();/popMatrix();` calls. Do read the [2D transformations tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) for more info on how to do that.